# debuging drush with xdebug

Tags: drush

I'm trying to debug a segmentation fault (11) from drush.
I have xdebug installed. The command it's giving the error is the pm-disable.

$ drush dis "module" --debug --verbose: 
...

Calling hook drush_pm_disable [11.17 sec, 84.08 MB]                                                                                             [debug]
Segmentation fault: 11

I think the issue is when it is calculating the dependencies, as I was also getting this on features/create, but disabling the dependencies checkbox in the features settings makes the features/create work well.

Comment: Don't forget this is a Q+A site...do you have a question?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is how to debug drush, you could use your IDE in the commands file you've got the command in pm.inc most probably, and use xdebug with the idkey, i.e.

```
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM";
```

See [debuging drush with xdebug](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118618/debuging-drush-with-xdebug) for more information

Also related: [Can Xdebug be triggered by Drush commands?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25144/can-xdebug-be-triggered-by-drush-commands)