# How to debug Drush command with xdebug in vscode?

Tags: drush, debugging

I reviewed a lot of articles (including [Can Xdebug be triggered by Drush commands?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25144/can-xdebug-be-triggered-by-drush-commands?rq=1)) about debugging Drush commands in PHPStorm with settings `xdebug.idekey`. They suggested export `XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name"` or set `xdebug.idekey` in the php configuration file. I can confirm that I have set xdebug.idekey in php.ini

The weird thing is that vscode [php debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension does not provide any setting for `idekey`. It is very different from other IDE. But I still can use the vscode to debug with Drupal site.

Any one knows how I can make xdebug working on Drush command?

Here is my xdebug configuration extracted by command `php -i | grep xdebug`. All these values are the same as the output from `phpinfo()`

```
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
IDE Key => sublime.xdebug
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => sublime.xdebug => sublime.xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /tmp/xdebug.log => /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Settings value of PHP debug extension

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "php",
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "request": "launch",
            "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/docroot",
            "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/Sites/independent01-dev/docroot",
            "port": 9000
        },
    }
}
```